# Limit number of process in docker

Tags: security, docker, sandbox

I'd like to use docker as a sandbox to run unsafe code. It seems to be quite safe, however a container is still exposed to forkbomb attack.

[I read it was possible to add options in /etc/init/docker.conf](https://devlearnings.wordpress.com/2014/08/22/limiting-fork-bomb-in-docker/)

```
limit nproc 20 100
limit nofile 50 100
limit fsize 102400000 204800000
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I'm using Debian 7.8 x86_64.

Comment: Can you add the version of Docker that you are using and how you are installing it?